# Get all users in sharepoint online

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, claims-based-identity

**Goal:**
Using powershell, get all users and their `AboutMe` property values from sharepoint online user profile.

**Problem**
Tried `Get-SPOUser`, followed [MS TechNet: Get-SPO User](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161389.aspx), also tried[TechNet Script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-get-all-the-users-3bc917b0/view/Discussions#content), but it only returns a few admin users, not all users.

I believe this is because all user accounts in SPO are like this:

```
i:0#.f|membership|doris.lee@contoso.com
```

I need to loop through claim based collection instead of basic SPO-User collection. I am not sure which object or collection has `"i:0#.f|membership|doris.lee@contoso.com"` and how to access it?

Comment: Please check this question. this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795790/getting-all-users-from-sharepoint-online-tenant-and-set-userprofile-property-via?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Anit. You pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Getting all users is simple :

```
Get-SPOUser -Site 'https://TenantName-my.sharepoint.com/'
```

AFAIK : getting the AboutMe property isn't that hard, but it does require using the SPO REST API or CSOM (and that involves quite some code to get the login flow properly : after that getting data out of the API is quite trivial)

Comment: bluuf: as I said, already tried  Get-SPOUser -Site 'https://TenantName-my.sharepoint.com/'   only gives me a few admin users, not all users.

Comment: If you have all correct permissions on your account and you only get a few results instead of the full list of users you'll have to enter a support ticket for microsoft. If i issue this command I get all SPO users returned.

Comment: You lack -LimitAll property